# Get values of the dataframe as a vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df, where I need to get the values as vector like shown below. Is it possible to achieve?

```
df
ColA  ColB
asd     23
dsf     354
fds     45
gfd     32
```

Expected output

```
('asd',23) ('dsf', 354) ('fds', 45) ('gfd', 32)
```

Comment: As a character vector?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

```
sprintf("('%s', %d)",  df[[1]], df[[2]])
# [1] "('asd', 23)"  "('dsf', 354)" "('fds', 45)"  "('gfd', 32)"
```

Comment: I think that's a good answer but does op really wants ``('asd', 23)`` with ``(`` included?

Comment: @Gainz We can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an atomic vector with the given structure because you have mixed data types and a nested structure. At least, that is how I interpret your required output.

The crude solution uses a loop and a growing list. That is neither elegant nor fast but it gets the job done. Note the argument `stringAsFactors` in the df assignment. If your data frame interpreted `ColA` as factor the result will look different. You have to make sure it is not a factor but a character column.

```
df <- data.frame(ColA = c("asd", "dsf", "fds", "gfd"), 
                 ColB = c(23, 354, 45, 32), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
result <- list()
for (r in 1:nrow(df)) {
  result <- c(result, df[r,])
}
result
```

A more elegant solution uses `mapply`.

```
result <- mapply(function(x, y) list(x, y), df$ColA, df$ColB)
result
```